# I'm in java looking for a string in a multidimensional array of characters, but my search stops after different characters for different words. Why?

Tags: java, loops, multidimensional-array, return, traversal

So I have a multidimensional array in java that holds a grid of characters. I am trying to match a string to characters in the grid. So far I have implemented searches for left to right, right to left, top to bottom, and bottom to top. They work, but not all the time.

The problem I am having is lets say for example I am searching for a string "ALGOS" which is in the grid from left to right. It finds an A, then finds another A, then finds an L, then stops. It should find an A, then L, G, O, S. The error I get is below:

```
A Found at: [0, 0]
A Found at: [1, 4]
L Found at: [1, 5]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
  at WordFind00.findWord(WordFind00.java:59)
  at WordFind00.main(WordFind00.java:45)
```

Here is my code - what could be going wrong?
Parts of it are commented out for testing each direction.

```
          public static String findWord(char[][]board, String word) {

            for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {

                    if (board[row][col] == word.charAt(0)) {

                        // search to the right
                        for (int letters = 0; letters < word.length(); letters++) {
                            if (word.charAt(letters) == board[row][col+letters]) {
                                System.out.println(word.charAt(letters) + " Found at: " + Arrays.toString(new int[] {row,col+letters}));
                            } 
                        } // end search to the right

                        /*// search to the left
                        for (int letters = 0; letters < word.length(); letters++) {
                            if (word.charAt(letters) == board[row][col-letters]) {
                                System.out.println(word.charAt(letters) + " Found at: " + Arrays.toString(new int[] {row,col-letters}));
                            }
                        } // end search to the left 

                        // search down
                        for (int letters = 0; letters < word.length(); letters++) {
                            if (word.charAt(letters) == board[row+letters][col]) {
                                System.out.println(word.charAt(letters) + " Found at: " + Arrays.toString(new int[] {row+letters,col}));
                            }
                        } // end search down 

                        // search up
                        for (int letters = 0; letters < word.length(); letters++) {
                            if (word.charAt(letters) == board[row-letters][col]) {
                                System.out.println(word.charAt(letters) + " Found at: " + Arrays.toString(new int[] {row-letters,col}));
                            }
                        } // end search down */

                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

If anyone wants to test it:
WordFind00.java: http://pastebin.com/DeNEQAsp
input.dat: http://pastebin.com/WyYF3wPA

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @Peter, yes it is. I have been stuck with this problem for a while and I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `if (word.charAt(letters) == board[row][col-letters]) {` - what happens if `col` is `0` (or `col-letters < 0`)? `if (word.charAt(letters) == board[row+letters][col])` - What happens if `row+letters >= board.length`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking the ranges of your array indicies, for example...

```
if (word.charAt(letters) == board[row][col-letters]) {
```

If `col-letters` is less than `0`, this will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, this goes for each of your checks...

You could do something like...

```
if (col - word.length() >= 0) {
    for (int letters = 0; letters < word.length(); letters++) {
        if (word.charAt(letters) == board[row][col-letters]) {
            System.out.println(word.charAt(letters) + " Found at: " + Arrays.toString(new int[] {row,col+letters}));
        } 
    } // end search to the right
}
```

Which will ensure that the `for-loop` is only ever run if the `col - word.length` does not expand beyond the start of the array.  If it does, then there's no real reason to attempt to even check the remaining cells.

You would need to apply this to all you conditions

**Updated**

The reason you're getting extract output is because the moment you find a matching character, you print it, regardless of whether you have a full match or not...here's a little cheat that will work for the horizontal checks...

```
String test = new String(board[row], col, word.length());
if (test.equals(word)) {

    System.out.println("Found [" + word + "] @ " + row + "x" + col);

}
```

Alternatively, if you must you loops, you could do something like...

```
if (col + word.length() <= board[row].length) {

    int letters = 0;
    while (letters < word.length() && word.charAt(letters) == board[row][col + letters]) {
        letters++;
    }

    if (letters == word.length()) {
        System.out.println("Found [" + word + "] @ " + row + "x" + col);
    }
}
```

Which basically checks to see if the number of matching characters equals the length of the original word or not...

Comment: Ok, so I added this in - thanks for that. However, now I am getting a different output. When I search for "ALGO" I get A, A, L, A, O, A, L, G, O, A, L, G, O. Why aren't I just getting A, L, G, O?

Comment: Probably because you have no exit condition from you loop once you're satisfied you've found the word you're looking for...

Comment: Yeah that's true, but even before the word I get letters I shouldn't.

Comment: Provide me with a runnable example so I can actually test it ;)

Comment: Ok, here is the full WordFind00.java program http://pastebin.com/DeNEQAsp, and here is the input.dat file http://pastebin.com/WyYF3wPA. You need to use the input.dat file to load the grid, but to test search strings, just change the string that is being passed in in the findWord method call.

Comment: So, basically, if you find even a single matching character, regardless of whether you get a full match or not, you print the result...You need to be checking to see if you actually have a full match or not...

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, your error is because you are not checking your indices. All you need to do to resolve this is check that the word won't go over the length of the array in your current direction.

Secondly, you don't have an exit statement. So you'll keep looping until you've iterated over the entire board. You could try the following:

```
//If we can't fit the word in, don't bother trying
if(col - word.length() >= 0) 
{
    boolean foundWord = true;
    for (int letters = 0; letters < word.length(); letters++)
    {
       //Stop trying as soon as we find a character that doesn't fit
       //Search to the right
       if (word.charAt(letters) != board[row][col+letters])
       {
           foundWord = false;
           break;
       }
    }
    //We can only get here if we've looped through the entire word and found a match for all of it.
    if(foundWord)
    {
        //Yay! I'm not sure about your return value though. 
        return "foundString!";
    }
}
```

Finally, a minor nit-pick, although it doesn't matter for a small example and it's cleaner to look at and understand this way... you probably don't want to do the word loop for every direction. You could do the search in every direction inside that loop.